# how to share cart details through url

Tags: javascript, vb.net, caching, browser, webforms

I Have an e-commerce site.I want to implement a feature for sharing my cart details to someone.There is no login upto adding the items into cart.So there is no problem for sharing the details. if the user A add 3 items to the cart and share the link to user B through email or any social media,on clicking the url by B should able to see the same items in the cart where user A already added.I want to know its possible through browser cashing or cookies or any other methods.I am using Asp.net webforms and vb.net as server side.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You would need to save the data server side.

Comment: @George Thanks for the quick reply.I can do that.how i will share that through url

Comment: If you really wanted to you could just build the cart of items from a url with parameters which is read in the code behind to add items based on URL ID's.